# Running more than one execute function in python give error 'Unread result found' , how to run two or more mysql statments in python?

Tags: python, mysql

## My Code

**Second last line is showing error <Unread.result.found> but when i run it individually it run successfully**

```py
import mysql.connector as msqc
import numpy as np

db = msqc.connect(
    host="localhost",
    username="root",
    password=" ",
    database="hotel",
)
cur = db.cursor()

ss = 'SELECT one_bed ,Available_one_bed from rooms where Available_one_bed = "A" '
cur.execute(ss)
available_room = cur.fetchone()
print(available_room[0])
cur.execute('SELECT * from rooms')
s = 'UPDATE rooms SET Available_one_bed = "N/A" WHERE one_bed = '+str(100)
cur.execute(s)
```

Comment: you are loading cursor with some results, (`cur.execute('SELECT * from rooms')`) but then not letting them go out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely not all data where read after first execute.
You need a buffered cursor, e.g.

```
cur = db.cursor(buffered=True)
```

some details could be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorbuffered.html